# Odata URI service troubleshooting

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, linqpad

I have an OData URI generated by a consumer desktop application like so

```
http://localhost:32702/TBC/Projects/15f1360adb2e4008921b9b5bb849ae78/
```

Entering this into my browser I can view the atom XML and see collections that should be available

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://localhost:32702/TBC/Projects/15f1360adb2e4008921b9b5bb849ae78/">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title> 
    <collection href="FeatureAttributes">
      <atom:title>FeatureAttributes</atom:title>
    </collection> -<collection href="Points">
      <atom:title>Points</atom:title>
    </collection> -<collection href="TotalStations">
      <atom:title>TotalStations</atom:title>
    </collection> -<collection href="Vectors">
      <atom:title>Vectors</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

So I then change my browser URI to include the Points collection or the Vectors collection

```
http://localhost:32702/TBC/Projects/15f1360adb2e4008921b9b5bb849ae78/Points
```

And it only returns the current date for each item I was expecting, no actual data. The count of items, however is accurate. I was hoping to be able to use this in a LinqPad or VB.Net query application, but I can't even get the browser queries to work. Is it me or is there an issue with the service? I've tried the URI in LinqPAD and in a test project with WCF Data Services and when I test the same URI I get a (500) Internal Server Error.

The vendor is not providing any support, so I was hoping someone here could give me some troubleshooting steps to show where the issue is at.

Edit:

- I modified IE options > Content > Feed Settings by unchecking "Turn on feed reading view"
  This allowed me to see the data from the returned entity collection. I can now try to use WebRequest to consume the XML data in a .net application.
- Adding $metadata to the URI in the browser yields "Website cannot display the page". Which leads me to guess that only feeds are exposed and no services. I'm not sure if this is possible.
- I'm still unable to use this URI in LinqPad or in visual studio using Add Service Reference. VS returns error "An error occurred while attempting to find service at URI.

Comment: what's your meaning of "it only returns the current date for each item I was expecting, no actual data". And, it seems that the service you use does not handle "$metadata"....

Comment: IE was set to feed reading view, which only displayed a limited stylized view of the xml data showing the current date for each item. Maybe I should have added the first item in my orig. comment as 1/2 an answer. Still don't know why $metadata or WCF data service is failing.

Comment: I am not sure about Lingpad, but the service may contain some issues. Is it possible that you can check the code of service?

Comment: No, The service is originating from a commercial desktop application. I don't have anything else to go on other than the URI. Also, the vendor support isn't helping either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about LinqPad, but "Add service reference" in Visual Studio expects a link to your $metadata endpoint or the service document (i.e., the first query in your question). You can access the Points collection using both of those tools as a secondary step.

I'm not sure why your $metadata endpoint is not showing up though. If you right-click and "view source", do you see the xml document there?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to see the xml document, but not by using view source. I had to uncheck Turn on feed reading view. If I use /Points after the URI. If I use /$metadata after the URI IE error "Website cannot display page"  HTTP 500. I guess I'm going to work toward using the WebRequest and build my queries manually using LINQ to XML.